# Can't upload a file to a s3 bucket on Flask with gunicorn

Tags: flask, amazon-s3, file-upload, gunicorn

I have a flask app that uploads an image received from a user to a s3 bucket.
When I run the app with a simple python command, it uploads the file just fine to the bucket. However, if I run the app with gunicorn, it throws TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object with the exactly same code.
I tried everything but nothing seems to fix it. There isn't much information on this problem here, either. Can someone please shed me a light on what could be causing this problem? Here are the snippets of the relevant code. I'm running the app with this command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 3 --timeout 600 wsgi:app`

```
# app.py 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if 'file' not in request.files or not request.files['file'].filename: 
        return 'No file is provided', 400

    file = request.files['file']
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    file.save(temp_file.name)
    image = cv2.imread(temp_file.name) 
    
    service = Service()
    try:
        filename = file.filename
        service.upload_image(file, filename)
```

```
# wsgi.py (same directory as in app.py)

from app import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
# service.py 

class Service(object):
     
    def upload_image(cls, image, name):
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY'),
            aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
        )
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            image,
            os.getenv('AWS_BUCKET_NAME'),
            name
        )
```